# Proof by induction that $n^2 < n!$

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

Prove $n^2 < n!$.

This is what I have gotten so far

basis step: $p(4)$ is true
Inductive Hypothesis assume $p(k)$ true for $k \ge 4$

Inductive Step $p(k+1)$ : $(k+1)^2 < (k+1)!$

$$(k+1)^2 =k^2 + 2k + 1 < k! + 2k +1$$

Can someone please explain the last step this is from text, I need help understanding this, forgive me for the formatting error Im still learning

Comment: its 2 sorry not n

Comment: In the last step, you are using the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Can you explain how is that true < (k+1)! ?

Comment: I explained that in my answer below...

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140396/prove-by-induction-that-n2n and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462423/proving-n-n2-by-mathematical-induction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inductive Step:

Assume the case for $n$ is true, then for $n \geq 4$ $$(n + 1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 < n! + 2n + 1 < n! + n^2 \leq n! + n!n = n!(n+1) = (n+1)!.$$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I misread! I fix rright now. This is what I get for being lazy.

Answer (score 1):

$$n^n \geq n!$$

Proof: Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then 
$$ n^n = n\cdot n\cdot n\cdot...\cdot n$$
where as 
$$ n! = n\cdot(n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot...\cdot1$$

For each term in the product you can compare
$$n = n $$
$$n > n-1 $$
$$n > n-2 $$ 
and so on. 
Thus $n^n \geq n!$