# Proving $n! > n^2$ by mathematical induction

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

I'm trying to prove that $n! > n^2$ for $n\geq 4$ by use of mathematical induction, but I get to the inductive step and get lost. But I'm struggling with the inductive step as expected.

Answer (score 0):

$4!=24>16=4^2$, so the basic step holds. Then:

$$ (n+1)! = (n+1) n! \color{red}{>} (n+1) n^2 > (n+1)(n+1) = (n+1)^2 $$
and we are fine. We used the inductive hypothesis in $\color{red}{>}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: multiplying $$n!>n^2$$ by $n+1>0$  we get $$(n+1)!>n^2(n+1)$$ and now you have to show that $$n^2(n+1)>(n+1)^2$$ which is easy.

Comment: You probably start from $$n!>n^2,$$ not $$(n+1)!>(n+1)^2.$$

Comment: this step is trivial i have it not forgotten, what is the matter with you?

Comment: The matter with **you** is that you cannot even set correctly a proof by induction (and we will not mention *initialization* so that kids won't be afraid...).

Comment: yes you have ritgh, i have made a typo, sorry for it!